# What is reason that on mapreduce sometimes the mapper generates more documents than the original data in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am performing a state-wise population count and getting extra documents with the original output. To check the reason i found that mappers would generate intermediate data a lot of more than the original data in mongodb . How can i resolve this ? The total count of document in source collection is 29468.

Sample from the Dataset:

```
{ "city" : "SPLENDORA", "loc" : [ -95.199308, 30.232609 ], "pop" : 11287, "state" : "TX", "_id" : "77372" }

{ "city" : "SPRING", "loc" : [ -95.377329, 30.053241 ], "pop" : 33118, "state" : "TX", "_id" : "77373" }

{ "city" : "TOMBALL", "loc" : [ -95.62006, 30.073923 ], "pop" : 19801, "state" : "TX", "_id" : "77375" }

{ "city" : "WILLIS", "loc" : [ -95.497583, 30.432025 ], "pop" : 9988, "state" : "TX", "_id" : "77378" }

{ "city" : "KLEIN", "loc" : [ -95.528481, 30.023377 ], "pop" : 35275, "state" : "TX", "_id" : "77379" }

{ "city" : "CONROE", "loc" : [ -95.492392, 30.225725 ], "pop" : 1635, "state" : "TX", "_id" : "77384" }
```

map function:

```
var m=function(){ emit(this.city,this.pop);}
```

reduce function:

```
var r=function(c,p){ return p;}
```

MR output to a new collection :

```
{ "_id" : "81080", "value" : 172 }
{ "_id" : "81250", "value" : 467 }
{ "_id" : "82057", "value" : 60 }
{ "_id" : "95411", "value" : 133 }
{ "_id" : "95414", "value" : 226 }
{ "_id" : "95440", "value" : 2876 }
{ "_id" : "95455", "value" : 843 }
{ "_id" : "95467", "value" : 328 }
{ "_id" : "95489", "value" : 358 }
{ "_id" : "95495", "value" : 367 }
{ "_id" : "98791", "value" : 5345 }
{ "_id" : "PLEASANT GROVE", "value" : [ 8458, 15703, 80, 772,
{ "_id" : "POINTBLANK", "value" : 2911 }
{ "_id" : "PORTER", "value" : [ 13541, 19024, 985, 425, 2705 ]
{ "_id" : "SHEPHERD", "value" : [ 9604, 17397, 2078 ] }
{ "_id" : "SPLENDORA", "value" : 11287 }
{ "_id" : "SPRING", "value" : [ 33118, 8379, 21805, 8540 ] }
{ "_id" : "TOMBALL", "value" : 19801 }
{ "_id" : "WILLIS", "value" : [ 9988, 2769, 2574 ] }
{ "_id" : "KLEIN", "value" : 35275 }
```

Comment: This is just complaining without an objective. Clearly state what your actual intention is. Your example is trivial

Comment: Furthermore how is this even a question? More results than what? Based on what? Is the data source active with new records being written? If you can't change this soon I've flagged you for close. Please ask a question. This doesn't even come close. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Neil as stated above the specified data on mapreduce , my objective is to get statewise population from dataset which worked but to increase my knowledge and be clearer in mongodb i requested for help

Comment: my question was edited by Lambda Dusk which might have misguided u

Comment: there is no new records being written its mere a raw imported dataset which i m using to perform the operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output isn't as expected because your `reduce` function is incorrect. The prototype for a `reduce` function is `function(key,values) {...}`, where `values` is an array associated with the `key`.

Your `reduce` function is returning the `values` array rather than reducing it.

To sum up the values for a given key, your `reduce()` function should look like:

```
  var r=function(key, values) {
     return Array.sum(values);
  }
```

If you want to calculate population by state, your `map()` function is also incorrect: you should be emitting the state & population instead of city & population:

```
  var m=function() {
     emit(this.state,this.pop);
  }
```

Putting that together, your output should end up looking like:

```
    {
        "_id" : "AK",
        "value" : 550043
    },
    {
        "_id" : "AL",
        "value" : 4040587
    },
    {
        "_id" : "AR",
        "value" : 2350725
    }
    ...
```

The MongoDB manual has further details on writing and testing your `reduce` function:

- [Requirements for the `reduce` function](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#mapreduce-reduce-mtd)
- [Troubleshooting the `reduce` function](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/troubleshoot-reduce-function/)

Comment: thanks for input , but even if i change my reducer code as suggested and perform the city wise population count its still gives some extra records { "_id" : "12462", "value" : 53 }
{ "_id" : "21858", "value" : 89 }   i m seeking reason for this result otherwise the logic is correct
{ "_id" : "23013", "value" : 103 }
{ "_id" : "23020", "value" : 724 }
{ "_id" : "23042", "value" : 207 }
{ "_id" : "23114", "value" : 443 }
{ "_id" : "23137", "value" : 1563 }
{ "_id" : "23157", "value" : 313 }
{ "_id" : "23973", "value" : 796 }
{ "_id" : "24329", "value" : 159 }
{ "_id" : "24633", "value" : 1571 }

Comment: What `out` option are you using for your Map/Reduce? Can you try an inline Map/Reduce and check the counts: `mapReduce( m, r, { out: { inline: 1 } } )`. Given your data and count of documents in source collection, I'm guessing you are using the [sample zip code data set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/) linked from the MongoDB documentation. With my adjusted Map/Reduce functions I get:  "counts" : {
  "input" : 29467,
  "emit" : 29467,
  "reduce" : 170,
  "output" : 51
 }

Comment: The reason I asked about `out` options is that it seems like your "extra" values don't match either city or state names. This could be the case if you are using the `merge` or `reduce` [output options](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#mapreduce-out-mtd), which will retain existing values in the output collection. To be sure, you could also drop the output collection before running your Map/Reduce.

Comment: i tried using replace and also by dropping the collection but result is still the same

Comment: @PratikShah: What do your counts look like from the output of the Map/Reduce command (i.e. input, emit, reduce, output)?

Comment: > db.rb.count();
29468
> var r=function(c,p){ return p;}
> var m=function(){ emit(this.city,this.pop);}
> db.rb.mapReduce(m,r,{out:{replace:"mr"},jsMode:true});
{
        "result" : "mr",
        "timeMillis" : 2414,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 29468,
                "emit" : 29468,
                "reduce" : 3885,
                "output" : 16698
        },
        "ok" : 1,
}

Comment: i think the extra documents i m specifying generated due to jsMode: true. If i make this is false it throws error code : 10075, this is because the reducer i used returns the value directly. You can only use jsMode for result sets with fewer than 500,000 distinct key arguments to the mapper’s emit() function. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/.  In this case how can i go furthur

Comment: @PratikShah: Per my answer, your original `r()` reduce function is incorrect and won't return a useful result. Per your M/R counts, your `m()` function is emitting one value per document (the city) of which 3885 are reduced (those are keys with more than one value) and the output collection has 16,698 results (which is certainly less than the 29,468 you started with). It looks like everything works as expected: correct your M/R functions if you want to calculate population by state ;-).

Comment: thank you for your input and immediate reply , helped a lot ,will rectify code